# How to remove first n columns containing blanks from text file by linux shell scripting

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I want to remove the first 6 columns containing blanks of this text file `sample.txt`

```
      2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
                 foo   bar
      2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
                 lorem ipsum
                 bar   foo
      2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
      2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
      ...
```

by linux shell scripting, e.g. by using `sed`, `awk` and/or `cut`.

Hence the **expected output** is

```
2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
           foo   bar
2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
           lorem ipsum
           bar   foo
2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
...
```

I've searched in SE, but only found solutions to remove all blanks at the beginning of each line, e.g.

```bash
$ sed 's/^ *//' sample.txt > output.txt
```

which results in this file

```
2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
foo   bar
2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
lorem ipsum
bar   foo
2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
...
```

where the formatting of the columns is lost.

Unfortunately this call of `sed`

```bash
$ sed 's/^ {6}//' sample.txt > output.txt
```

doesn't work.

**Hence how could I remove the first 6 columns containing blanks by linux shell scripting?**

Comment: Did you try: `sed -E 's/^ {6}//' sample.txt > output.txt` ?

Comment: @anubhava: This works for me. Please post it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Or escaping your current code `sed 's/^ \{6\}//' sample.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @HatLess: This works too. I have too poor knowlegde in shell scripting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or if you know the first 6 characters are always spaces, `cut -c 7- sample txt`

Comment: @Shawn: `cut -c 7- sample.txt > output.txt` works too. Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output with lines where only the first 2 characters are spaces, and the 3rd character is non-blank? What is the expected output with lines which have tab characters initially instead of spaces?

Comment: My text file always contains 6 blanks at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed -E 's/^ {6}//' sample.txt > output.txt
 awk '{gsub(/^ {6}/,""); print > "output.txt"}' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing arbitrary columns from a text file could be done by `colrm` on linux shell.
This command line tool from IBM is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=files-removing-columns-in-text-colrm-command).

Hence removing the first 6 columns from `sample.txt` could be done by

```bash
$ colrm 1 6 < sample.txt > output.txt
```

resulting in the desired output

```
2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
           foo   bar
2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
           lorem ipsum
           bar   foo
2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove *n* first characters from each line, then GNU `AWK` [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function is handy, let `file.txt` content be

```
  2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
             foo   bar
  2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
             lorem ipsum
             bar   foo
  2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
  2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
  ...
```

then

```
awk '{print substr($0,7)}' file.txt
```

output

```
2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
           foo   bar
2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
           lorem ipsum
           bar   foo
2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
...
```

Explanation: `print` part of current line (`$0`) starting at `7`th character.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 2):

it's brute force but gets the job done :

```
mawk{1,2} NF++ FS='^      ' OFS=
{n,g}awk  NF++ FS='^ {6}'   OFS=
```

~

```
2022-05-26 Mary  Jane
           foo   bar
2022-05-27 Tom   Powels
           lorem ipsum
           bar   foo
2022-05-28 Honky Tonk
2022-05-28 Hill  Billy
```